# Task.WhenAll and ContinueWith

Tags: c#

My service need to run both Job1 and Job2 at the same time (for performance sake). When both Job1 and Job2 are completed, then only it will run Job3. When Job3 is completed, then only run Job4. When Job4 is completed, then only run Job5. How do I make sure Job3 can only be run

This is my code. How do I make sure that Job3 can only run after Job1 and Job2 are completed? Do I need to add `ContinueWith` here?

```
await Task.WhenAll(RunJob1(cancellation), RunJob2(cancellation));

RunJob3(cancellation);
await RunJob4(cancellation);
RunJob5(cancellation);
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem with the existing code? why not await before RunJob3 and RunJob5 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's just this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(RunJob1(cancellation), RunJob2(cancellation));

await RunJob3(cancellation);
await RunJob4(cancellation);
await RunJob5(cancellation);
```

Assuming all jobs are `async`, of course.

You do not need `ContinueWith` as the `await` calls hold the code before moving on.

Comment: _"Assuming all jobs are `async`"_ - it's not the `async` keyword that matters, it's that they return a `Task` or ["`Task`-like"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/) result as you can `await` a non-`async` method provided that it returns a `Task`-like result - but you can't `await` an `async void` method.

Comment: But my Job3 and Job5 are not async Task methods.@Enigmativity

Comment: @Steve then you should mention what problem are you facing with your existing code.

Comment: @Steve - Your code sounds like it works, and you haven't given us enough information to go into it further than that.

Comment: I guess I will leave it as it is. I thought I need to use ContinueWith. thanks guys.